# Google Sheets referencing another sheet every nth row

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets, I want to grab the text value from a sheet and put it every three rows in a separate sheet. I want there to be blank spaces in the rows in between.

For example, say I have a list of names on a sheet called "Customer Info" In Column A. On a separate sheet, I am keeping track of interactions with customers, and that data takes 3 rows. Every third row, I want to grab the name of the next customer from my sheet "Customer Info" and put it in column A of my sheet "Transactions."

I've been trying to find a way to use something like ='Customer Info'!A(x), and use a formula to get the value of x. I thought some variation of MOD would work.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1):

Say *Sheet2* is like:

[image]

In *Sheet3* cell **A1** enter **1** and in **A2** enter:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(),3)=1,1+MAX($A$1:A1),"")
```

and copy downwards.  In **B1** enter:

```
if(A1="","",index(Sheet2!A:A,A1))
```

and copy downwards:

[image]

You can change the number of empty rows by changing the arguments to `MOD()`.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(TRIM(FLATTEN(SPLIT(QUERY(INDIRECT("Customer Info!A2:A"&
 COUNTA(A2:A)+ROW(A2)-1)&"♀ ♀ ♀",,9^9), "♀"))))
```

[image]